# Insert into on duplicate key update faster

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

This is my query

```
INSERT INTO temp.filecompsinorg(sha256,hostId)
SELECT sha256,hostId FROM indic.fileso limit 20000
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastSeen = NOW();
```

- temp.filecompsinorg has 70m records(UNIQUE INDEX `uniquness` (`sha256`, `hostId`)).
- indic.fileso will give 20k record.

This update takes about 2 minutes. Way to long for me.

Is this a normal time frame for this amount of records?

Is there any way to improve this query?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE temp.filecompsinorg` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`.  I suspect you have a small cache, hence thrashing disk to get through _nearly_ 20K _randomly_ located blocks.

Answer (score 0):

20k records in two minutes is about 200 updates/second (there are 120 seconds in 2 minutes).  The `on duplicate key update` means that the load is bigger than just inserting a record -- it also involves at least one index lookup and potentially an `update` rather than an `insert`.

Performance depends on the available hardware (which the question does not specify), but hundreds of such operations in a second does not seem unreasonable.  Investment in hardware and memory might speed it up a bit.